# Fix the headers in a responsive table angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am new to the `webDevelopment.` Before posting this, I have gone through all the answers but none of them were working for me. So, I am asking this question. I have a table where I added

```
overflow-y:scroll;
height:100px;
```

using this I am getting the scrollbar but My table headers are not fixed. so, can any one please help me with this ?

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 nopadding">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered col-xs-12 col-lg-12">
            <thead class="text-center text-info text-capitalize">
            <th class="text-center">Sr.No.</th>
            <th class="text-center">Document</th>
            <th class="text-center">Score</th>
            <th class="text-center">Actions</th>
            </thead>
            <tr ng-repeat="file in processResumeFiles">
                <td class="text-center">{{ file.id}}</td>
                <td class="view-orphan uploadResumeTableCellOverFlow">
                    {{ file.attributes.name}}
                </td>
                <td class="text-center">{{file.totalScore}}</td>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <button class="btn btn-labeled  btn-info" title="click to see" ng-disabled="!file.attributes.isUploadedDocument" data-ng-click="somemethod($index)">
                        <i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </button>
                    <button class="btn btn-labeled  btn-info" title="click to see" ng-disabled="!file.attributes.isCommitted || !file.attributes.isUploadedDocument" data-ng-click="somemethod(file.attributes.name)">
                        <i class="fa fa-share" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </button>
                    <button class="btn btn-labeled  btn-info" title="click to see" data-ng-click="somemethod(file.attributes.name)">
                        <i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </button>
                    <button class="btn btn-labeled  btn-info" title="click to see" ng-disabled="!file.attributes.isCommitted || !file.attributes.isUploadedDocument" data-ng-click="somemethod(file.attributes.name)">
                        <i class="fa fa-sign-out" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </button>
                    <button class="btn btn-labeled  btn-info" title="click to see" ng-disabled="!file.attributes.isCommitted || !isjdDeleted || !jdSelected"
                            data-ng-click="somemethod(file.attributes.name)">
                        <i class="fa fa-check-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why would you expect them to be fixed? What you could do is just set the `overflow-y: scroll;` on the `tbody` instead of the table element but this would require the elements to be displayed as `block`

Comment: Because, in the ng-repeat the table is having more than 100 entries so , I just want to add a scrollbar for that table. because of this , I want the headers should be fixed.

Comment: Not working using overflow-y:scroll on tbody

Comment: You would also need the `display: block` as I said, but that will do a lot of harm

Comment: tried.. but its just moving the positions of headers.

Comment: cab you please tell me what can be the solution ?

Comment: I tried to add a css height and scroll to tbody but its not getting applied to the tbody any reason ?

Comment: probably these suggestions aren't working because they're asking you to add it on an element that you don't have on your table (tbody). See my answer below.

Comment: Can you create a plunker so that we can see what the problem is and solve them

Answer (score 0):

There's a jQuery plugin here that does the job for you: [fixed header table](http://www.fixedheadertable.com)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
.table-fixed thead {
  width: 97%;
}
.table-fixed tbody {
  height: 230px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.table-fixed thead, .table-fixed tbody, .table-fixed tr, .table-fixed td, .table-fixed th {
  display: block;
}
.table-fixed tbody td, .table-fixed thead > tr> th {
  float: left;
  border-bottom-width: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
table {
    width: 100%;
}

thead, tbody, tr, td, th { display: block; }

tr:after {
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
    clear: both;
}

thead th {
    height: 30px;
    text-align: left;
}

tbody {
    height: 120px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

thead {
    /* fallback */
}


tbody td, thead th {
    width: 19.2%;
    float: left;
}
```

You see in fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/zLgzwn56/

Comment: After this , column headers misaligned with data this problem is happening.

Comment: `thead th {` remove comment on `text-align`, please check updated code

Comment: using a less file for css . so, using it like .table   don't know how to use thead, tbody, tr, td, th { display: block; } in less file

Comment: headers are not fixed with this thing

Comment: after doing this still I am getting the same issue if misaligned headers.

Answer (score 0):

First of all Add: `table-layout: fixed;` to your table element.

Also to be semantic correct, add tbody for the content on your table (it's missing in your example).

Then add `overflow: auto;` and a height to tbody. See example: https://codepen.io/tjvantoll/pen/JEKIu

Comment: Hey, I used .tableBodyScroll tbody {
display:block;
max-height:300px;
overflow-y:scroll;
}
.tableBodyScroll thead, tbody tr {
display:table;
width:100%;
table-layout:fixed;
}  this css, now the problem is with the alignment of the headers with the body content.column headers misaligned with data .can you tell me why ?

Comment: hard to know without taking a look at your current HTML - you could be missing some cells. Create a codepen with the actual markup and it could be easier to help.